# How to have a next page for post?

Tags: pages

I have a theme installed but my problem is that the theme doesn't provide a next page function. So if I have 20 posts, and I put 10 in the *Blog pages show at most* in Reading Setting of Wordpress Setting, it only shows the 10 posts and then I can't anymore see the remaining posts on my home because it doesn't have any next button. I want to have a next page button so that the users can still view the other posts by clicking the next button. How can I do this? Need help. Asap! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the functions `next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()` for that.

You have to place these functions in your theme where you want the links to be seen. Possible templates for that are your archive.php, category.php depending on your needs.

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
    <div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
</div>
```

More info:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link